# Add multiple pages on theme activation

Tags: wordpress

Could not find anything about this on the web so, is this possible that I add several pages within the function.php file when the theme is newly installed?

Comment: This sounds more like a job for using WP-CLI

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but not straight forward you could use the after_switch_theme hook

```
add_action("after_switch_theme", "mytheme_do_something");
```

Nice tutorial below for one way to do the actual creating.

https://clicknathan.com/web-design/automatically-create-pages-wordpress/